# unable to instert date in sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am trying to insert date in sqllite through a function.

**PROBLEM**
The problem that i m facing is date is not inserted in the table and showin error at logcat.
**code** 
code of database

```
package com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;



public class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private  static int DATABASE_VERSION =9;
    public   static final String DATABASE_NAME = "browse6.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bookmark";
    public  static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_title = "Title";
    public  static final String COLUMN_url = "Url";
    public  static final String COLUMN_creatd = "created at";


    public databasehelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_title + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_url + " TEXT," + COLUMN_creatd + "DATETIME );");
    }

@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


   public void addContact(databasemodel d) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_title, d.gettitle()); // Contact Name
        values.put(COLUMN_url, d.getURL()); // Contact Phone
       values.put(COLUMN_creatd,d.getDateTime());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public ArrayList<databasemodel> getAllContacts() {
        ArrayList<databasemodel> contactList = new ArrayList<databasemodel>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                databasemodel structure = new databasemodel();
                structure.setid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                structure.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                structure.setURL(cursor.getString(2));
                structure.setTIME(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(structure);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

}
```

code of getdate function is

```
 public String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "E, MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return  dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

**logcate error**

```
04-30 14:29:02.075 2454-2454/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting created at=Sun, Apr 30 2017 02:29:02 PM Title=Google Url=https://www.google.co.in/webhp
                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "at": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO bookmark(created at,Title,Url) VALUES (?,?,?)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                                                     at com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser.databasehelper.addContact(databasehelper.java:56)
                                                     at com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser.browser$2$3.onClick(browser.java:158)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Maybe your column  `created at` should be `createdAt` or something

Comment: thank u @EpicPandaForce for ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *blank space* in your table name which is causing the syntax error:

```
public  static final String COLUMN_creatd = "created at";
```

You can use underscore or remove the space between created and at. You may **Modify** this to :

```
public  static final String COLUMN_creatd = "created_at";
```

If you want to keep the blank space **use** `[]`:

```
public  static final String COLUMN_creatd = "[created at]";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after removing the space it is showing this ***error04-30 15:23:08.566 2523-2523/com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting created_at=Sun, Apr 30 2017 03:23:08 PM Title=Google Url=https://www.google.co.in/webhp
                                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table bookmark has no column named created_at (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO bookmark(created_at,Title,Url) VALUES (?,?,?)***

Comment: The above error is occurring because your created table name is still `created at` . Update your table name to `created_at` or if removing stored data doesn't matter to you just simply update database version to 10 : `DATABASE_VERSION =10;` then re-run your app.

Comment: i already  tired updating database version.but  still getting the error. even changed the database name to create a new database

Comment: Still getting the same error ? Are you editing the public string as : `public  static final String COLUMN_creatd = "created_at";` and using as `COLUMN_creatd` while creating and inserting into table ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam  yes, bt i  also tired declaring a new static final string variable and using it instead of colum_creatd.

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error. As @Rotwang said, uninstall the app, change db version, clean build your project, then re-install the app. Hope fully your issue will be solved.

Comment: i think something wrong with my Android studio . and thanks for help @tahsinRupam .@Rotwang

Comment: @tahsinRupam When uninstalling and reinstalling, the db version can be left as is. Just to say.